# How to optimise Canvas drawing in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

How to optimise Canvas drawing in WPF, when i have 10000 Line like in program "Paint"? When I draw in "Paint" i can use how much I need lines and circles, but in my program agter +-10000 i have lags.
I create a test program with 10000 lines and when I move mouse on canvas rectangle is change position to a cursor.
here code

```
for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Line l = new Line();
            l.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            l.StrokeThickness = 1;
            l.X1 = 50+ privi;
            l.Y1 = 50 + privi;
            l.X2 = 100 ;
            l.Y2 = 100 + privi;
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(l);
            privi += 5;
}
```

and here i moving

```
if (clicked)
        {
            Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(p.X-25, p.Y - 25, 0, 0);
        }
enter code here
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
privi = 5;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;
rect.Width = 50;
rect.Height = 50;
MainCanvas.Children.Add(rect)
```

Comment: What is rect? Do you draw the lines at initialization only? What sounds strange is the dimension that Canvas should have. Supposing privi = 0, when i = 10000, l.X1 = 50050...

Comment: @SimoneCifani rect it`s rectangle which i try to move on canvas. This way i check a lags.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand where is the Rectangle. Looking at the code, lines are drawn directly in the Canvas. Does rect contain MainCanvas or it is another object in it?

Comment: @SimoneCifani Yes, Rectangle is child of MainCanvas. 
We have MainCanvas, inside him we have 10000 lines and 1 rectangle.
When i try to move rectangle i has so much lags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if you need lines and rect to be in the same canvas, otherwise I found that adding the rectangle in a second transparent canvas over the MainCanvas improves the reactivity.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1080" Width="1024">
    <Canvas Name="MainCanvas" MouseMove="MainCanvas_MouseMove">
       <Canvas Name="RectCanvas" Background="Transparent" MouseMove="RectCanvas_MouseMove">
       </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    double privi = 5;

    Rectangle rect;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Line l = new Line();
            l.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            l.StrokeThickness = 1;
            l.X1 = 50 + privi;
            l.Y1 = 50 + privi;
            l.X2 = 100;
            l.Y2 = 100 + privi;
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(l);
            privi += 5;
        }

        rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 50;
        rect.Height = 50;            
        rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);
        SecondCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
    }

    private void RectCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (clicked)
        {
            Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(p.X - 25, p.Y - 25, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read question one more please!
"...when I move mouse on canvas rectangle is change position to a cursor..."

Not **MouseDown**, but **MouseMove**.
Everything is ok, not as i have, but it`s the same.

Comment: @VovaDowhanych: I edited my post with my proposal. Don't know if it fits your requirements. Still a bit confused on `if (clicked)` inside MouseMove event...